# Python 3 Perl-like/Ruby-like shift operator for Array with O(1) complexity?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x

I would like to use shift, as available in Perl/Ruby, in Python. The straightforward way is pop(0). Is it an O(1) operation, because I saw different answers, from O(n) to O(1)...
If not, is there a way to get the O(1)? Average O(1) is good enough, and I do not need a strictly worst-case
Thanks.

Comment: What is the use case here? Do you absolutely have to pop it out of the list? or can u skip the first one and use an iterator?

Comment: Absolutely? No. It's just "nicer" that way, and may help with memory consumption. I have ways to not need this feature.